# Does Pytorch 1.4 support cuda10.1?

Tags: python, pytorch

I try to install pytorch 1.5+cu101, but it can't find `caffe2_nvrtc.dll`(it indeed exists in `lib\caffe2_nvrtc.dll`). So I try to install pytorch 1.4+cu101, but I can not find such wheel(only pytorch1.4+cu100/cu92) from https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html.
Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyTorch 1.4.0 shipped with CUDA 10.1 by default, so there is no separate package with the `cu101` suffix, those are only for alternative versions. You just need to install the regular `torch` package:

```py
pip install torch==1.4.0 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html
```